# Getting google sheets to stop changing formulas when pulling in responses

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet that is attached to a form on my website.  It's using gravity forms for wordpress.  Not sure what changed, but now every time a new submission comes in from the form it makes the formulas change on other sheets.  I've done the $ signs in the formulas but it's still changing.  The formulas are based off of the response sheet capturing all the answers.

How can I lock the formulas so they don't change every time a new response comes in?  I want it always pulling from A2, even when new responses come in.  I've seen the "Indirect" formula suggestion but my formulas are already complex.  Here's one:

=ArrayFormula(vlookup(transpose(split(query(rept(row(Sheet1!$A$2:A)&" ",Sheet1!$B$2:B),,9^9)," ")),ArrayFormula({row(Sheet1!$A$2:A),Sheet1!$A$2:R}),{2,19},0))

This formula works perfectly, and once I change it all back to A2 after the first response comes in it works fine... but I make a new sheet with every form and I also reset the sheets when I turn forms on and off. I would like to not have to change it every time a first response comes in for every sheet.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

use in row 1:

```
={"header"; INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
 QUERY(REPT(ROW(Sheet1!A2:A)&"", Sheet1!B2:B),,9^9), " ")), 
 {ROW(Sheet1!A2:A), Sheet1!A2:R}, {2,19}, ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Form responses are always inserted in newly created rows that cannot be referenced directly in advance.

The usual recipe to work around this is to dynamically copy form responses to another sheet where the values can be referenced normally. To do this, choose **Insert > New sheet** and place this formula in cell `A1` of the new sheet:

`={ 'Form Responses 1'!A1:F }`

...where F corresponds with the last form responses column that you want to copy.

Then modify your formulas to reference the new sheet instead of the form responses sheet.